# How can I add a URL to a query string?

Tags: php, parameters, get, query-string

I have a small problem with my PHP script.  I want to be able to have a URL within a query string so it would look like this:

```
http://example.com/?url=http://google.com/
```

This works absolutely fine and `$_GET['url']` will return `http://google.com`.

The problem is when the URL in my query string already has query string, for example:

```
http://example.com/?url=http://www.amazon.com/MP3-Music-Download/b/ref=sa_menu_mp3_str?ie=UTF8&node=163856011
```

will return:

```
http://www.amazon.com/MP3-Music-Download/b/ref=sa_menu_mp3_str?ie=UTF8
```

and I want it to return:

```
http://www.amazon.com/MP3-Music-Download/b/ref=sa_menu_mp3_str?ie=UTF8&node=163856011
```

I am using PHP for server side.

Could anybody please help?

### Update

I am using `Codeigniter`, so if this is the reason why it isn't working as it should then please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode the url passed as query argument:

- If you send it from PHP, use `urlencode` or `rawurlencode`.
- If you send it from JS, use `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: Thanks,  I will use that! I might also just switch to the POST method as well!

Answer (score 1):

Use [urldecode()](http://fr.php.net/urldecode) to pass query string

Comment: urlencode() ... I got the question wrong first also ... or perhaps the OP is not clear enough? I now don't know ;)

Comment: Thanks! I am using jQuery, but the urlencode() function will come in useful as my app progresses! ;)